# WCF - Using ServiceRoutes instead of svc files -- My app states I need AspNetCompatability only when I first attempt to connect?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, url-routing, svc

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    private static void RegisterRoutes(ICollection<RouteBase> routes)
    {
        routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Calculator", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(CalculatorService)));
    }
}

<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
    <serviceActivations>
      <add factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory"
           relativeAddress="Calculator.svc"
           service="MyServer.CalculatorService"/>
    </serviceActivations>
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>
</system.serviceModel>
```

When I do this and go to http://localhost/MyApp/Calculator.svc I get an error saying I need AspNetCompatability. So I added `[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]` and it works, the only thing is I'm worried that I will want my service to use alternative means of transport (not just http) if I want to get into using alternative non-http bindings.

The strange thing is that if I don't set the attribute to Allowed or Required then when I rebuild my page I get that error. After I get that error I hit refresh and everything is fine. And it isn't just if I query the svc through a web browser, but if I have an app it crashes the first time it connects (if the server was restarted) and afterwards it works. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your problem is messed configuration. You are adding a route and in the same time you are registering the service with configuration based activation. Use either one or second. Also you can use routes and only Http based protocols or non-http protocols but without routes.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, yes, you must enable ASP.NET compatibility to use `ServiceRoutes`. This is because the ASP.NET runtime is now responsible for routing the traffic instead of just IIS modules.